# What happened to the AppleMasters?

Tags: apple-inc

What happened to the celebrity [AppleMasters<sup>†</sup>](http://www.apple.com/applemasters) program that used to live on Apple's website? Is it closed down? Are there any fan sites out there for the AppleMasters?

<sup>†) link defunct</sup>

Comment: Please open a thread on [meta] if the close reason doesn't make sense...

Answer (score 2):

From [AppleMasters wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleMasters):

> The AppleMasters program was launched in 1996.<sup>[[3]](http://findarticles.com/p/articles/mi_hb3270/is_200012/ai_n7969242)</sup> Based on findings at archive.org's WayBackMachine, Apple removed the program from their web site on or before August 7, 2002.<sup>[[4]](http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.apple.com/applemasters)</sup>

So it seems the feature has been long gone, which can be confirmed from the linked [Internet Archive crawl index](http://web.archive.org/web/*/http://www.apple.com/applemasters).

As for the "fan sites": I found one self-proclaimed fan site: [kdunn.org](http://www.kdunn.org/). It currently hosts two videos—presumably related to AppleMasters.

You would probably have much better results [searching the YouTube for AppleMasters](https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=applemasters) than searching for fan sites *per se*.

Comment: Thanks Koiyo. Good work. I also found this thread on AppleInsider.com forum: 
[link](http://forums.appleinsider.com/t/34587/whatever-happened-to-applemasters) AppleInsider Forum